# Can we use Bluetooth Low Energy to unlock an android device?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Specifically can we unlock an android device using BLE without Google Play Services and Google's Smart Lock API?

Comment: can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: Well, it can be split into two questions: 1) Can you unlock an Android device programmatically and 2) Can you either scan for BLE devices or run a GATT server in the background in a locked Android device. The first is probably possible with the right permissions granted by the user and I'm not sure of the second one as all kinds of background tasks are harder and harder to run with each Android platform update. A ForegroundService probably helps. You could study those two topics to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Well a HID over GATT device, acting as a keyboard can press enter, put in the PIN and then enter again. Then you unlock the screen. Other than that, excluding Smart Lock, you can't do more than a normal app would be able to do.